# Corner label with an icon on a img

Tags: html, css

I have an image in the HTML that I want to slap a corner label with icon on when the user clicks on the image.

Could someone help me creating a css class that I can slap on to an  to give it a corner label with an icon like shown in the attachment.

so my code would look as follows

```
<div> 
  <img src="blahblah.jpg">
  <img src="another.jpg" class="image-label">
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

In this case the first image would appear as normal. The second one would have the corner label/icon combo as shown in the attached image.

Can someone tell me what `image-label` css class would put a corner with a background color (e.g. blue) and then put the font awesome 'heart' icon centered in that corner label/icon as shown in the image.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: can u plz explain clearly? i tag should be center..remaining can u plz explain?

Comment: I don't think you need another image to hold the **heart** icon, just a `<div>` with `border-radius` should suffice

Comment: And have you tried something to do this? Can you also include it in the question? We can start there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly using font awesome for the heart, so no need for another image. Use a div to hold the icon and position it with border-radius like this

```css
.image-container{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  margin:100px;
}
.image-container img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
.image-label{
  width:60px;
  height: 60px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:skyblue;
  font-size:30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  transform:translate(50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://www.gqmiddleeast.com/sites/default/files/gqme/styles/766_431_landscape/public/images/2019/06/12/Tony-Stark.jpg?itok=7-QNeRCi">
  <div class="image-label">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: is there a way to maintain the photo's original dimensions and not have any cropping or scaling and still have the blue/black heart appear on the corner of the image?

Comment: i just made width and height = 'fit-content'. Thanks everyone for your help!